# Query is not working as expected when using multiple when condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying implement search in laravel eloquent. It is not working as expected below are my code

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $dateFrom = $request->has("dateFrom") ? $request->get("dateFrom") : null;
    $dateTo = $request->has("dateTo") ? $request->get("dateTo") : null;
    $status = $request->has("status") ? 0 : 1;
    $requestName = $request->has("name") ? $request->get("name") : null;;
    $query = User::where('is_donor', $status)->has("bloodDonationHistories");
    $resources =$query
        ->when($requestName, function ($q) use (&$requestName) {
            return $q->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                 ->orWhere('permanent_address', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                 ->orWhere('temporary_address', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('blood_group', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->whereRelation('district',function ($qu) use (&$requestName){
                    $qu->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%');
                });

        })
        ->when($dateFrom !== null && $dateTo !== null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom, &$dateTo) {
            return $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]);
        })
        ->when($dateFrom !== null && $dateTo == null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom) {
            return $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [$dateFrom, Carbon::parse($dateFrom)->addDay()]);
        })
        ->when($dateFrom == null && $dateTo !== null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom, &$dateTo) {
            return $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [Carbon::parse($dateFrom)->addHours(-1), $dateTo]);
        })
        ->paginate($this->paginationLimit);
    return UserResource::collection($resources);
}
```

Debug Query

```
SELECT *
 FROM `users`
 WHERE (
`is_donor` = 0
and EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `blood_donation_histories`
  WHERE `users`.`id` = `blood_donation_histories`.`user_id`
    and `blood_donation_histories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
)
or `name` LIKE '%kathman%'
or `phone` LIKE '%kathman%'
or `permanent_address` LIKE '%kathman%'
or `temporary_address` LIKE '%kathman%'
or `blood_group` LIKE '%kathman%'
and EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `districts`
  WHERE `users`.`district_id` = `districts`.`id`
    and (`name` LIKE '%kathman%')
)
)
 and `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Problem is I am getting data from is_donor is 1. it is not respecting `is_donor` = 0. I am doing anything in my code.

Comment: Why do you have all your `use` variables passed by reference? This is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group those `OR` condition between parenthesis. You can do it like this

```
$resources = $query
    ->when($requestName, function ($q) use ($requestName) {
        $q->where(function($parenthesis) use ($requestName) {
            $parenthesis->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('permanent_address', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('temporary_address', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhere('blood_group', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%')
                ->orWhereRelation('district', 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $requestName . '%');
        });
    })
    ->when($dateFrom !== null && $dateTo !== null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom, &$dateTo) {
        $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]);
    })
    ->when($dateFrom !== null && $dateTo == null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom) {
        $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [$dateFrom, Carbon::parse($dateFrom)->addDay()]);
    })
    ->when($dateFrom == null && $dateTo !== null, function ($query) use (&$dateFrom, &$dateTo) {
        $query->whereBetween('donor_verified_at', [Carbon::parse($dateFrom)->addHours(-1), $dateTo]);
    })
    ->paginate($this->paginationLimit);
```